# Как в беспроводной сети данные отправляются лишь на конкретное устройство?

Tags: wifi, wireless

Учитывая, что беспроводная связь основана на распространении радиоволн, у меня есть вопрос, на который я не могу найти ответ.
Предположим, как WiFi роутер отправляет информацию на конкретный телефон? Ведь радиоволны распространяются по всему пространству вокруг?
Или, например, если мы звоним кому-то на телефон, радиовышки распространяют колебания вокруг себя, проходя сквозь сотню других телефонов. Почему звонок возникает только на том телефоне, на который мы звоним?
Ведь радиоволны не направляются конкретно в направление одного устройства. На своём пути колебания проходят сквозь множество устройств, но действия возникают только на ОДНОМ

Моё предложение: что радиоволны содержат в себе определенный идентификатор устройства, и проходя сквозь каждое устройство идёт проверка. Если идентификатор соответствует текущему устройству - выполняется закодированное действие, если нет - просто ничего не происходит

Не могу найти в интернете описание этого принципа "идентификации" и как информация (радиоволны) поступают лишь на конкретное устройство. Единственное предположение: вот как раз что эти колебания проходят абсолютно сквозь все устройства находящиеся на пути распространения волны, а на техническом уровне уже реализована проверка идентификатора

Comment: [CDMA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDMA), [TDMA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TDMA), [FDMA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/FDMA)

Comment: Когда учитель в классе говорит "Петров, к доске", то к доске идет Петров, а не весь класс, хотя звуковые волны доходят до каждого ученика. Примерно так же и в беспроводной (да и проводной тоже) сети.

Comment: @Эникейщик Очень хороший пример. Но хотелось бы узнать принцип этой идентификации "Петрова"

Comment: в первом комментарии аж три ссылки. Узнавайте.

Answer (score 0):

В среде wifi у кадра есть 5 адресов:

- адрес назначения DA
- адрес источника SA
- адрес приёмника RA
- адрес передатчика ТА
- адрес сети BSSID

В кадре передается 3 из них в зависимости от того, кто кому передает информацию. В редких случаях (старые ретрансляторы) используется 4 адреса. CDMA

```
ToDS    FromDS  Адрес1  Адрес2  Адрес3  Адрес4
0       0       DA      SA      BSSID   —
0       1       DA      BSSID   SA      —
1       0       BSSID   SA      DA      —
1       1       RA      ТА      DA      SA
```

Биты ToDS - принимает точка доступа, FromDS - передает точка доступа.

Всё устройства в зоне действия слышат все передачи. Если на одном канале есть несколько точек доступа, то скорость вайфай сети делится между этими точками.  TDMA

Современные роутеры с технологией beam-forming могут менять геометрию зоны действия и направлять антенну в сторону мобильного терминала. mu-mimo точки доступа могут формировать сразу несколько таких направлений.